# Button to Datagridview to textbox

Tags: c#, button, datagridview, textbox

```
private void dataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)

    {
        if (button1.text == "1")//its a category
        {
            int i;
            i = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
            textBox7.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            textBox6.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            textBox5.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            textBox3.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            textBox8.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
            textBox9.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        }
        if (button2.text == "2")//another category
        {
            int i;
            i = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
            textBox7.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            textBox6.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            textBox5.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            textBox3.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            textBox9.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
       }
 }
```

the button 1

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"Select * from Accessories", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable ();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

If I click the button1, it's right, but when I click button2, button1 get call!

Comment: Show code of buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, you have a problem in the if statements.

Your if statement gets executed if the text on `button1` is `1`, which remains true regardless of which button is clicked.

To solve the problem, use an integer variable and save different values in it in the `button1_Click` and `button2_Click` events, and use these values in the if statements instead of the text on the buttons.

This can be the sample code:

Button Click events:

```
int code = 1;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //your code
    code = 1;
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //your code
    code = 2;
}
```

The if statements:

```
        if (button1.text == "1" && code == 1)//its a category
        {
            int i;
            i = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
            textBox7.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            textBox6.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            textBox5.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            textBox3.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            textBox8.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
            textBox9.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        }
        if (button2.text == "2" && code == 2)//another category
        {
            int i;
            i = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
            textBox7.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            textBox6.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            textBox5.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            textBox3.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            textBox9.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
       }
```

Comment: string x = button1_Click();? how can i do that?

Comment: I don't understand what you actually want to do, because a method cannot be stored in a string variable! So, can you please explain what you actually want to do in the statement, string x = button1_Click();, so that I can help you?

Answer (score 0):

cause `buttn1` still have the `TEXT==1` and I don't know what is your code under of `buttn2`..!

Did u handle  it?

Comment: my code in button2 is same with button1 but the "accessories" is "other"

Comment: its Must be Work Now  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"Select * from Accessories", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;


         Button1Click = true;
    }
    bool Button1Click = false;
    bool Button2Click = false;
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /////another category
         Button2Click = true;

    }

    private void dataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (button1.text == "1" && Button1Click)//its a category
        {
            int i;
            i = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
            textBox7.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            textBox6.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            textBox5.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            textBox3.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            textBox8.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
            textBox9.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();


        }

        if (button2.text == "2" && Button2Click)//another category
        {
            int i;
            i = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
            textBox7.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            textBox6.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            textBox5.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            textBox3.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            textBox9.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();

        }
    }
```

I just did Simple way to Control ur Click EventHandler.

Comment: Nothing is Happening, and it only disable the cellclick

Comment: its Must be Work Now  :)

Comment: Error, i think, its because the button1 have 7columns and button2 is 6columns.

Comment: I don't Know your Error, but I think your first data table in category first have more or less columns than data table in another category .so check those category and make sure your data tables have same columns index .